# What are some interesting relationships between pi and phi?

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-picture

Phi is the golden mean solution to the 1/x=1+x and pi the transcendental number relating the radius of the circle to its area.

A side note: while there are really interesting series converging to pi, I thing it's impossible to give a coordinate free proof it's equivalence to the ratio between the area and radius if a circle.

Is there any way to use the golden ratio to define pi, that could then possibly lead to a coordinate less relationship between geometric pi and pi as a series?

Answer (score 6):

**Q:** *Is there any way to use the golden ratio $\Phi$ to define $\pi$ ?*

[image]

as proven by [John Baez](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2017/03/07/pi-and-the-golden-ratio/).

Comment: OK good answer, still, I would love if there was a way to somehow define an infinite series that would compute the area or circumference of a circle without using sine, unless one can define and  relate sine to geometry without coordinates.

Comment: @Ezio the discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791063/egg-vs-chicken-trig-functions-exponential-real-and-complex might interest you. Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078377/defining-sine-and-cosine or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303044/axiomatic-definition-of-sin-and-cos or probably many other related questions over there.